# How can i customize date picker in flutter like that

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, coding-style

[I have a project and designer demanding the date picker like that anyone help how to customize it like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdNB8.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a package called [table_calendar](https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar) or review the following [page](https://fluttergems.dev/calendar/) for more packages about calendars.